# 10 SFF in 1U case, identify please

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

Could you please identify this OEM/ODM case? I've dreamed about 10 disks in 1U from the day I was born. I know many server brands offer 8, but I wish I can have ten. ) The problem is guys sell it only as full server with warranty included, asking too much.

It looks like Intel(or DELL), but it is not. I checked supermicro, asus, lenovo, tyan sites, all none.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `The problem is guys sell it only as full server with warranty included, asking too much.` - soo you want just disks without any logic attached, without any warranty? Sounds a bit odd. That looks like a small SAN device, and a SAN device is really just a normal server with a crapload of disks, and a special OS...

Comment: I just want to put my favorite E-ATX motherboard, RAID controller, disks etc. in this case, test everything and then bring it to datacenter to use for my web projects. Seller offer limited selection of motherboards and processors, and ask too much for everything. I don't need their warranty, because it's cheaper and faster to buy and change part myself on place, server is far from  mission critical.

Comment: ah, I understand now.

Comment: The front of the drive caddies look exactly like a Dell. Are you sure that it's not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *might* be the SuperMicro SC116 -- http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/1u/?chs=116

Comment: SC116 looks like a contender: http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/1U/116/SC116TQ-R700U.cfm - different drive trays, but still 10xSFF

Comment: Ahh.. I typo-ed the model number.. got the link right.

Comment: Dell probably went to the same chassis OEM :-)

Answer (score 6):

That's the [Dell Poweredge C1100](http://www.dell.com/content/products/superview.aspx?c=us&cs=555&l=en&pageoverride=gallery_view1&s=biz&xdb=Z2xvYmFsOnByb2R1Y3RzOnBlZGdlOmZsYXNoOnBvd2VyZWRnZS1jMTEwMCNyZWdpb24=)  Look at the second pic.  I don't know why someone scratched off the Dell logo on your pic.

Comment: I thought they looked like Dell disk caddies...

Comment: Oh, thanks! I wonder how this possible, they sell it under their own name.

Comment: People will attempt to resell anything..  The Poweredge C class is pretty interesting. It came out of the DCS group. They aren't encumbered by the DRAC nor did they originally even support Windows installations! They use Intel NICs and support 1333Mhz RAM (unlike the standard Poweredge line.) You can send me an email if you'd like a contact at Dell that can get you more info.